# "'_reactNative.default.create' is undefined" Cant seem to find any solution

Tags: mobile, view, react-native, typeerror

SO I created a project and copied components, assets and config folder from other laptop to this one. In this new project, I resolved dependencies still I am stuck at this error and cannot find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

*

> ```
> > TypeError: _reactNative.default.create is not a function. (In
> > '_reactNative.default.create({
> >     screen: {
> >       flex: 1
> >     },
> >     view: {
> >       flex: 1
> >     }   })', '_reactNative.default.create' is undefined)  ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable
> > module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that
> > the application entry file path is incorrect.
> >       This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
> ```

- 

[image]

Comment: Hard to see the issue without the code base itself.  Whatever that create function is for, it looks like its either missing an import or a package to be installed on that screen.

Comment: I can't find that function anywhere used.